# Proving the upper bound of cross correlation

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, random-process

I am reading about cross-correlation from this [document](http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/84-85/1/ce695/resources/root/R.P%20Concepts/m10686.pdf) and equation (5) states that

> The maximum value of the crosscorrelation is not always when the shift
> equals zero; however, we can prove the following property revealing to
> us what value the maximum cannot exceed
> $$R_{xy}(\tau) \le \sqrt{R_{xx}(0)R_{yy}(0)}$$

However, I could not find any proof for this equation. Does anyone have a resource regarding this property?

Comment: I think this is done using the cauchy schwartz inequality. Start with E[(x - y)^2]

Answer (score 1):

The  document cited by the OP actually states that
$$|R_{X,Y}(\tau)| \leq \sqrt{R_X(0)R_Y(0)}\tag{1}$$
which implies what the OP wants to prove, namely that
$R_{X,Y}(\tau) \leq \sqrt{R_X(0)R_Y(0)}$ but also tells us
that $R_{X,Y}(\tau) \geq -\sqrt{R_X(0)R_Y(0)}$.

Recall that for jointly wide-sense stationary processes (which are, of course, individually wide-sense stationary too and thus have constant (possibly nonzero) means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$), the definitions of the functions in $(1)$ are
$$ R_X(\tau)\stackrel{\Delta}{=} E[X(t)X(t+\tau)],\quad R_Y(\tau)\stackrel{\Delta}{=} E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)],\quad R_{X,Y}(\tau)\stackrel{\Delta}{=} E[X(t)Y(t+\tau)]$$
where, because of the wide-sense stationarity assumption, the functions depend only on $\tau$, and not upon $t$. Note also that the means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ of the random processes are not involved at all, much to the sorrow of those who prefer to demean their processes before calculating correlations and thus end up with the *autocovariance*  and *cross-covariance* functions instead of autocorrelation functions and cross-correlation functions as they are defined and understood in the communications and signal processing literature.

Now consider the quantity $$E\left[(\alpha X(t)\pm\beta Y(t+\tau))^2\right]
= \alpha^2 R_X(0)+\beta^2 R_Y(0) \pm 2\alpha\beta R_{X,Y}(\tau)$$ which, being the expected value of a nonnegative random variable, must be nonnegative for all choices of real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Thus,
$$\pm 2\alpha\beta R_{X,Y}(\tau) \leq \alpha^2 R_X(0)+\beta^2 R_Y(0)\quad \forall ~\alpha, \beta$$ or equivalently, for every possible choice of *positive* real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it must be that
$$2\alpha\beta |R_{X,Y}(\tau)| \leq \alpha^2 R_X(0)+\beta^2 R_Y(0). \tag{2}$$
*Choosing* $$\alpha^2 = \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{R_Y(0)}{R_X(0)}},
\quad \beta^2 = \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{R_X(0)}{R_Y(0)}}$$
so that $\alpha^2\beta^2=\frac 14$, we see that Eq.$(2)$ reduces to
$$|R_{X.Y}(\tau)| \leq \frac 12 \sqrt{R_X(0)R_Y(0)} + \frac 12 \sqrt{R_X(0)R_Y(0)}$$
which is $(1)$.

Comment: That was a beautiful answer. It also looks like you now agree that the correlation is a scaled version of the covariance. It's good to see that.

Comment: @markleeds Sorry to disappoint you but I have completely re-written my answer to eliminate references to covariance and correlation being a scaled version of covariance.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But are you then saying that your original answer where you explicitly stated the scaled relationship was incorrect ?

Comment: Dilip: I was being a smart alec in my original post just to try and help you to see that it's okay to be wrong once in a while. It's happened to me many times and, each time, the world never ended. All the best.

Comment: @markleeds The correlation _coefficient_ $\rho$ of two random variables is a scaled covariance; the **autocorrelation** function $R_X(\tau)$ (in the meaning generally accepted on dsp,SE) of a wide-sense-stationary random process  is **not** a scaled _autocovariance_ function: $C_{X}(\tau)$ equals $R_X(\tau) - \mu_X^2$, not $aR_X(\tau)$ for some positive constant $a$.

Comment: Okay. It seems to be the case that your definition of a wide-sense stationary process is called a covariance function in statistics. So, let's not start the whole argument over :).