# Power Spectral Density and Wiener–Khinchin theorem for 2 different stochastic processes

Tags: power-spectral-density, random-process, theory

I know the famous Wiener-Khinchin theorem for stationary random processes: the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of a stationary random process is equal to the Power Spectral Density of the process.

Is there such a result for 2 different stochastic processes?
I mean, is there a known relation involving the PSD of the individual processes on one hand, and their correlation function on the other hand?

I make my question more clear with a derivation. Let $x$ and $y$ be 2 random processes.
Let $$
G_{xy}(f) = \lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2T}X_T(f) Y_T^*(f) 
$$
with
$$
X_T(f) = \int_{-T}^{T}x(t)e^{-i2\pi ft}dt
$$
and similar for $Y_T(f)$. Then:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G_{xy}(f)e^{i2\pi f \tau} df = \lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X_T(f) Y_T^*(f) e^{i2\pi f \tau} df \\ =  \lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X_T(f) \int_{-T}^{T}y(t)e^{i2\pi ft} dt e^{i2\pi f \tau} df \\
= \lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} y(t) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X_T(f) e^{i2\pi f (t+\tau)}df d\tau \\
= \lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} y(t) x(t + \tau)dt
$$

This looks like the result that I want, i.e. $G_{xy}(f)$ is the Fourier transform of the correlation function. Is this true or am I mistaken in the derivation?

Best,

Clément

Comment: Search for "Cross-spectral density" and "Cross-correlation function". The most general result is essentially the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality bounding the maximum value of the cross-correlation function in terms of the maximum values  of the two autocorrelation functions. You need weasel words such as jointly stationary etc to make the whole thing work: Individual stationarity does not imply joint stationary.

Comment: Thank you, these are indeed the right key words. Wouldn't you have a good reference for this? I found a few references but they all lack the theoretical background that I am looking for. For example, they simply state: "the cross spectral density is the Fourier transform of the correlation function" (has if it was satisfying as regards the meaning).

Comment: The calculation that you have now included is sort of right in spirit but wrong in many ways. The most important point is that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are _random variables_, not names of real signals, and for jointly wide-sense-stationary random processes, the cross-correlation function $R_{x,y}(\tau)$ is defined as $E[x(t)(y*t+\tau)]$, and not as the limit of the integral that you have written. That integral is a random variable, and whether the limit that you have written is valid in any sense is open to question. More....

Comment: Continued...   A useful reference might be M.B. Pursley's _Random Processes in Linear Systems,_ Prentice-Hall 2002, many parts of which also appear In his _Introduction to Digital Communications,_ Prentice-Hall 2005.

Comment: $|R_{x,y}(\tau)| \leq \sqrt{R_x(0)R_y(0)} ~\forall~\tau $ is the bound I referred to. A proof is given in [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70119/235) in this forum.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I will check this reference. I am aware that $x$ and $y$ are random process, my integral are then random variables dependent on the trajectories. Questions (nonetheless): isn't it true that $$\lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} y(t) x(t + \tau)dt$$ should be equal to $\mathbb{E}[x(t) y(t+\tau)]$ under the right hypothesis (like joint stationarity and ergodicity) ? The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is interesting but does not connect the correlation function to the frequency content of $x$ and $y$ in the way that the Wiener-Khintchin theorem does.

Comment: If you treat $x(t)$ and $y(t)$  as random variables, then for each positive real number $T$, the integral is a _random variable_ and so, when you are taking limits, you need to specify in what sense that sequence of random variables is converging to the alleged limit: distribution, probability, mean-square, or almost surely (a.k.a. with probability $1$) etc, not just _what_ the limit is. In this instance, _for jointly wide-sense-stationary processes,_ the limit is a degenerate random variable that takes on constant value $R_{x,y}(\tau) = E[x(t)y(t+\tau)]$with probability $1$.